# How to input data in span tag using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

```
   <div data-offset-key="hch7-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset- 
    key="hch7-0-0"><br data- 
   text="true"></span></div>
  <span data-offset-key="hch7-0-0"><br data-text="true">
  <span data-text="true"></span>
```

I want to enter data in this last span tag with data-text=true, how do I do that with selenium(python)?

My code:(want to post something on the wall of a group on facebook), I opened the post box successfully but I cant enter any input in that. That input is supposed to go in the last span tag in the HTML code above.

```
 path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

 def fun(gmailID,password):
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
     driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
     user = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
     user.send_keys(gmailID)
     pass_enter = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
     time.sleep(1)
     pass_enter.send_keys(password)
     pass_enter.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
     time.sleep(5)
     fb_link = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/'
     group_id = 'writersnbloggers'

     driver.get(fb_link+group_id)
      time.sleep(3)
      message = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 
     'Shivam?')]")
     message.click()
     time.sleep(2)
     post_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*span[@data-text="true"]')
     print(post_box)
     post_box.send_keys("hello")
     time.sleep(10)    

if __name__=="__main__":
      fun(id,pwd)
```

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: please ad screen shot also to know wat kind of element is it

Comment: code added @Wonka

Comment: screenshot attached @PDHide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"What\'s on your mind")]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[role="dialog"] form[method="POST"]')))

driver.switch_to.active_element.send_keys("something")
```

you can use switch to active element instead ,to focus on the current active element that is the create post

Comment: Thanks, this works, can you explain how did you find where to write('div[role="dialog"] form[method="POST"]')  after you clicked the whats on your mind box

Comment: That's the dialogue that opens up after you click that field

Comment: Thanks, i got it now @PDHide

Answer (score 1):

Try this python code:

```
WebDriver driver;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"div._1mj>span:last-child\").setAttribute(\"data-text\", \true\");");
```

Demonstration how it will work:

```js
var lastSpan = document.querySelector("div._1mj>span:last-child");
console.log("Before : ");
console.log(lastSpan);
lastSpan.setAttribute("data-text", "true");
console.log("After : ");
console.log(lastSpan);
```

```html
<div class="_1mf _1mj" data-offset-key="hch7-0-0">
  <span data-offset-key="hch7-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span>
  <span data-offset-key="hch7-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span>
  <span ></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not that comfortable with js, will love if someone can solve this with python.

Comment: the above cell of code is python code.
Below are HTML and JS just to demonstrate how it will work